# Foundry not outputting console.log (solidity)

Tags: solidity

Followed docs at https://book.getfoundry.sh/reference/forge-std/console-log

Tests are passing but console.log is not doing anything. I excepted it would print the output in the terminal.

Test contract is as follows:

```
pragma solidity =0.8.17;
import "forge-std/console.sol";
import "forge-std/Test.sol";

contract ProjectTest is Test {
  ProjectRouter router;

  function setUp() public {
    router = new ProjectRouter();
    console.log("DONE"); // NOT WORKING
  }

  function test() public { // PASSED
    string memory name = router.name();
    assertEq(router.name(), "Router");
  }

  function test123() public { // PASSED
    console.log(123); // NOT WORKING
  }
}
```

Tried

```
contract ProjectTest is console, Test
```

But that gave more than 256 errors which look like this:

```
error[9097]: DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.
    --> lib/forge-std/src/console.sol:2090:3:
     |
2090 |   function log(bool p0, bool p1, bool p2, uint p3) internal view {
     |   ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
Note: The previous declaration is here:
  --> lib/forge-std/lib/ds-test/src/test.sol:19:5:
   |
19 |     event log                    (string);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Solution was provided in the following link: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/142744/foundry-not-outputting-console-log/142784#142784

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, make sure you have the latest version of foundry. Simply run

  `foundryup`
- Then, you actually don't need to import `forge-std/console.sol`. It should be enough to import `Test.sol`.
- Lastly, remember that when you run tests, the logs are not output by default. To run a test displaying logs, you can specify

  `forge test -vv`

Otherwise, check different verbosity levels here:
https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/tests#logs-and-traces

Answer (score 1):

When typing console.log, foundry will give you list of types that you can use,
for example, to print out string "DONE", use

```
console.logString("DONE");
```

To print out number you wrote everything right, exept, forgot about ""

```
console.log("123");
```

For more info check
https://github.com/TateB/foundry-docs/blob/master/src/reference/forge-std/console-log.md